# Codepen live view full/back screen issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I have written some HTML, CSS, and JS to create a small and fun project which was working fine in both editor as well as live mode, but unfortunately, now the live view mode is not working correctly, also my code is all fine. Here is my codepen project link https://codepen.io/affu-72/full/jOxaLWw

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Spice&display=swap" 
  rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Clock</title>
</head>
```

Comment: What is the issue showing?

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.